# Visual Studio support for GIT with multi-project solutions

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, version-control

When I used Visual Studio solution options to integrate my Solution with my GIT repository it told me that some files were not copied and would appear in the output window. Well nothing appeared in the VS output window but the second project in the solution did not make it to the repository.

I know this sounds familiar to several other questions here but I need to tackle it from the Visual Studio perspective. (Submodules, Subtrees, Mono Repos, and multiple Branches) Of those solutions/approaches Subtrees seems to be the most applauded but VS does not integrate well :-(

Then I find VS Support for multi-repo solutions. Is this what is recommend or what people are doing? There are very many multi-project solutions out there that must have solved this problem already.

Can someone share/point-to a multi-repo solution that can be cloned and the local solution copy opened and built in VS seamlessly?

Are clones of multiple repos required?